# SQL: Trying to select two meta_values in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT meta_value 
FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE meta_key = "bid_resource_lat" 
AND meta_key = "bid_resource_lng"
```

I'm trying to select two rows within one query, as you can see above ... and I can't wrap my head around why this isn't working...

And how would I make sure that the two results are grouped together within a row?

Comment: Do you want this meta data for a particular post, or for all posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need "OR" as the logic is the wrong way round from as you're imagining it.

```
SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmetaWHERE meta_key = "bid_resource_lat" OR meta_key = "bid_resource_lng"
```

Explanation:

You want to get a row if the key is either the first OR if it's the second. This returns up to two rows. The way you wrote it then both conditions needed to be matched.

"I want a car that is italian OR expensive" - You can get a Ferrari, a Mercedes and a Fiat
"I want a car that is italian AND expensive" - You can get a Ferrari

Comment: Thanks! and would you happen to know how I can group these together? Instead of querying them as separate rows?

Comment: You get both together in the one results set. You'll need a while loop to navigate the rows. Example here http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php (search for "while" in the examples) if you're using PDO, but the logic is similar for other libraries.

Comment: perhaps you can help me out with the much more extended version of this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945702/sql-complicated-select-statement-and-returned-radius

Comment: I have answered. Probably not the answer you were quite looking for, but make sure you read it as it'll make your programming and debugging a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use an `OR` condition, not an `AND` condition:

```
SELECT meta_value 
FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE meta_key = "bid_resource_lat" 
OR meta_key = "bid_resource_lng"
```

Your query could not return any rows, because you're asking for records where the `meta_key` column is equal to ***both*** `"bid_resource_lng"` and `"bid_resource_lng"`, which can obviously never happen since one row will only have one value in the `meta_key` column.

Answer (score 0):

```
meta_key = "bid_resource_lat" AND meta_key = "bid_resource_lng"
```

Above will never be TRUE. Use OR instead
meta_key cannot be bid_resource_lat and bid_resource_lng at the same time.