# SQL: Complicated Select Statement and returned radius

Tags: mysql, sql, metadata

This query is driving me insane and I honestly just don't know how to accomplish it.

I need to grab all USERS and SHOPS longitude and latitude that are within a certain radius, and return back some other information attached to those resulting IDs... the radius part, I have figured out:

`( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('48.453541') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('-123.491765') ) + sin( radians('48.453541') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance`

^This radians in the statement above are just a random address that I want to query against.

But grabbing results that essentially are two different rows AS ONE result confuses me right out. Both tables are constructed in this manner:

```
id
meta_key
meta_value
```

So I need to grab the "meta_value" of two keys for both a USER and a SHOP ... the "meta_key"  for the USER is "bid_user_lat" and "bid_user_lng" ... and the "meta_key" for the SHOP are "bid_resource_lat" and "bid_resource_lng"

Ideal results (just showing one of each, but should be multiple, depending on radius):

```
id - 223
first_name - "Mark"
last_name - "Johnson"
bid_user_lat - 45.0000
bid_user_lng - -150.0000

id - 688
company_name - "Joe's Shop"
bid_resource_lat - 45.0000
bid_resource_lng - -150.0000
```

I really hope I'm explaining this correctly, because this is just driving me nuts!

---

My updated query is as follow, yet it's still not producing any results and it should:

```
SET @lat =  '48.453541';
SET @lng =  '-123.491765';
SET @radius =  '10000';

SELECT
    wp_usermeta.user_id,
    bid_user_lat.meta_value,
    bid_user_lng.meta_value,

( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( @lat ) ) * cos( radians( bid_user_lat.meta_value ) ) * cos( radians( bid_user_lng.meta_value ) - radians( @lng ) ) + sin( radians( @lat ) ) * sin( radians( bid_user_lat.meta_value ) ) ) )  AS distance 

FROM
    wp_usermeta
JOIN 
    wp_usermeta bid_user_lat
    ON wp_usermeta.user_id = bid_user_lat.user_id
    AND wp_usermeta.meta_key = "bid_user_lat"
JOIN
    wp_usermeta bid_user_lng
    ON wp_usermeta.user_id = bid_user_lng.user_id
    AND wp_usermeta.meta_key = "bid_user_lng"

HAVING distance < @radius ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this information by using self-joins:

```
SELECT
    table.id,
    bid_user_lat.meta_value,
    bid_user_lng.meta_value
FROM
    table
JOIN 
    table bid_user_lat
    ON table.id = bid_user_lat.id
    AND table.meta_key = "bid_user_lat"
JOIN
    table bid_user_lng
    ON table.id = bid_user_lng.id
    AND table.meta_key = "bid_user_lng"
WHERE
    { distance clause }
```

...the distance clause is where you ensure that it's within the proper distance. You can use `bid_user_lat.meta_value` as the `bid_user_lat` value, and `bid_user_lng.meta_value` as the `bid_user_lng` value in your calculation.

If you want to return the User results in the same query as the Shop results, then you can do the same query as the above one (using Shops instead of Users, of course), and connect them with a `UNION` or `UNION ALL`.

Side note:

If you have any control over the database, you may want to re-visit the design. The solution above is not ideal by any means... If a User always has a bid_user_lat and a bid_user_lng field, or even if it's just a common attribute of User, then it really should have its own column in the User table.

*Correction:*

I was `JOIN`ing incorrectly. The `ON` clause should use `bid_user_lng.meta_key = "bid_user_lat"` instead of `wp_usermeta.meta_key = "bid_user_lat"`. You also need to add a `GROUP BY` clause so that you don't have duplicate records. Applying these to your query above, you get:

```
SET @lat =  '48.453541';
SET @lng =  '-123.491765';
SET @radius =  '10000';

SELECT
    wp_usermeta.user_id,
    bid_user_lat.meta_value,
    bid_user_lng.meta_value,

( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( @lat ) ) * cos( radians( bid_user_lat.meta_value ) ) * cos( radians( bid_user_lng.meta_value ) - radians( @lng ) ) + sin( radians( @lat ) ) * sin( radians( bid_user_lat.meta_value ) ) ) )  AS distance 

FROM
    wp_usermeta
JOIN 
    wp_usermeta bid_user_lat
    ON wp_usermeta.user_id = bid_user_lat.user_id
    AND bid_user_lat.meta_key = "bid_user_lat"
JOIN
    wp_usermeta bid_user_lng
    ON wp_usermeta.user_id = bid_user_lng.user_id
    AND bid_user_lng.meta_key = "bid_user_lng"

GROUP BY wp_usermeta.user_id

HAVING distance < @radius ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

Here's confirmation that it works:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE wp_usermeta (user_id INTEGER UNSIGNED, meta_key VARCHAR(255), meta_value VARCHAR(255));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.25 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO wp_usermeta (user_id, meta_key, meta_value)
    -> VALUES
    -> (1, "bid_user_lat", "45.000"), (1, "bid_user_lng", "-150.000"),
    -> (2, "bid_user_lat", "20.000"), (2, "bid_user_lng", "20.000"),
    -> (3, "bid_user_lat", "-300.000"), (3, "bid_user_lng", "70.000");
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.16 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
    ->     wp_usermeta.user_id,
    ->     bid_user_lat.meta_value,
    ->     bid_user_lng.meta_value,
    -> 
    -> ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( @lat ) ) * cos( radians( bid_user_lat.meta_value ) ) * cos( radians( bid_user_lng.meta_value ) - radians( @lng ) ) + sin( radians( @lat ) ) * sin( radians( bid_user_lat.meta_value ) ) ) )  AS distance 
    -> 
    -> FROM
    ->     wp_usermeta
    -> JOIN 
    ->     wp_usermeta bid_user_lat
    ->     ON wp_usermeta.user_id = bid_user_lat.user_id
    ->     AND bid_user_lat.meta_key = "bid_user_lat"
    -> JOIN
    ->     wp_usermeta bid_user_lng
    ->     ON wp_usermeta.user_id = bid_user_lng.user_id
    ->     AND bid_user_lng.meta_key = "bid_user_lng"
    -> 
    -> GROUP BY wp_usermeta.user_id
    -> 
    -> HAVING distance < @radius ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
+---------+------------+------------+--------------------+
| user_id | meta_value | meta_value | distance           |
+---------+------------+------------+--------------------+
|       1 | 45.000     | -150.000   | 1271.3329043047352 |
|       3 | -300.000   | 70.000     | 4905.4310014631055 |
|       2 | 20.000     | 20.000     |  7198.549954690863 |
+---------+------------+------------+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for responding ... but I cannot seem to get this to work for me. And this doesn't account for SHOPS

Comment: After replacing the table name and the distance clause, what was your final query?

Comment: `SELECT
    wp_usermeta.user_id,
    bid_user_lat.meta_value,
    bid_user_lng.meta_value
FROM
    wp_usermeta
JOIN 
    wp_usermeta bid_user_lat
    ON wp_usermeta.id = bid_user_lat.user_id
    AND wp_usermeta.meta_key = "bid_user_lat"
JOIN
    wp_usermeta bid_user_lng
    ON wp_usermeta.id = bid_user_lng.user_id
    AND wp_usermeta.meta_key = "bid_user_lng"
WHERE
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('48.453541') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('-123.491765') ) + sin( radians('48.453541') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance`

Comment: `lng` and `lat` are not defined... You need to be using `bid_user_lat.meta_value` and `bid_user_lng.meta_value`.

Comment: That correction, while making sense, still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Also, your `WHERE` clause isn't a boolean expression -- it's just a calculation. It should be something like `WHERE {calculation} < 5`.

Comment: Actually, you're right. I need to include something like `HAVING distance < '1000' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20` Any idea how?

Comment: Just put your calculation into your `WHERE` clause. So if your calculation was `x + y + z`, then your query would end with: `WHERE (x + y + z) < 1000 ORDER BY (x + y + z) LIMIT 0, 20`.

Comment: Well, that allowed the query to run through ... but I'm not getting any results, and I should be. I edited my question above to show my latest query.

Comment: Replace all your single-quoted variable names with the actual variable. Ex: Replace `'lat'` with `@lat`. Your query is not using these variables; it's comparing strings.

Comment: Okay, thanks ... alas, I'm still not getting any results back. I keep thinking that `wp_usermeta bid_user_lat` is the issue ... I'm at a loss.

Comment: Do you get anything back if you remove the `HAVING` clause?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18204/discussion-between-dcolumbus-and-tomtheman5)